# array.splice not working it always delete last element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    add() {
    rendercomponent.push(UiInput);
    childJson.push(this.dynamicJson())
    this.setState({ documents: rendercomponent, Json: childJson });

}
componentDidMount() {
    rendercomponent.push(UiInput);
    this.setState({ documents: rendercomponent })
}
dynamicJson() {
    return {
        "service": this.state.formValues.text,
        "tax": this.state.formValues.tax,
        "amount": this.state.formValues.amount
    }
}
popComponent = (index) => {
    console.log(`in parent-->>${index}`)
    rendercomponent.splice(index, 1);
    childJson.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ documents: rendercomponent,Json: childJson,formValues:{} })

};  render() {
    return (
        <div>
    {this.state.documents.map((Element, index) => {
                                    return <Element key={index} index={index} onUpdate={this.onUpdate} popComponent={() => this.popComponent(index)} />
                                })}
          </div>
);
}
```

`array.splice` not working correctly it always deletes the last element from the array

In my UI there is one button to add component, on that button `add()` function is called

And also there is delete button, on delete button `popComponent()` function is called.

I want to delete the particular element, it always deletes the last element from the redercomponent array.

please help me to sort this problem

Comment: The code you've got above seems like a bit missing.

Comment: which thing is missing, i have put only necessary function into the question

Comment: can you post a small fiddle showing the problem

Comment: problem is that if i want to delete the 2 index no element or any element, it always delete the last element

Answer (score 0):

`splice` would mutate an object `rendercomponent`, but it won't change the reference of that object. If the reference does not change, the react won't re-render it, as it won't be different as per the react's diffing algorithm. So you can use `slice` instead of`splice`. Such that the new object's reference should be different for the earlier object.

Check that `rendercomponent!== rendercomponentModified`

perhaps

```
 popComponent = (index) => {
    console.log(`in parent-->>${index}`)
    var rendercomponentModified = [
     ...rendercomponent.slice(0,index),
     ...rendercomponent.slice(index+1)
    ];
    var childJsonModified = [
           ...childJson.slice(0,index), 
           ...childJson.slice(index+1)
    ];
     this.setState({ documents: rendercomponentModified,
    Json: childJsonModified,formValues:{} });
   }
```

Comment: @NandkishorShinde Please check now

Comment: popComponent = (index) => {
        var rendercomponentModified = [...rendercomponent.slice(0, index), ...rendercomponent.slice(index + 1)]

        if (rendercomponent != rendercomponentModified) {

            this.setState({ documents: rendercomponentModified })
        }
            childJson.splice(index, 1);
            this.setState({ Json: childJson, formValues: {} })
    };

Comment: i am write  function like that but it can't delete element, it add element equal to the index

Answer (score 0):

in case index is -1, `rendercomponent.splice(index, 1);` will just remove the last item of the array

Comment: Yes, but I want to delete specific element.

Comment: what i meant is `rendercomponent.splice(index, 1);` does delete 1 item at index position.
But somehow if index is `-1` then it will just delete the last item.

Comment: That's the problem redercomponent.splice(index,1 ) does not delete  1 item at index position, it delete last element, I want to delete item at  index position